# Laravel 5.4 : Best practice to parse variable to a view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

For example, I want to add a variable in my default view (default.blade.php)

I can of course, define my variable directly into the view file, like this :

```
@php ($user = Sentinel::getUser())
```

But this is not recommended.

Should I add it on AppServiceProvider.php ? (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#sharing-data-with-all-views)

But with which call ? Like this :

```
public function boot()
    { $user = Sentinel::getUser(); }
```

This get : Undefined variable: user

```
public function boot()
    { View::share('user', Sentinel::getUser()); }
```

This get Trying to get property of non-object, so Sentinel is not truly declare

Or in the a controller

```
public function __construct()
    {
        //user
        $user = Sentinel::getUser();
        view()->share('user',$user);            

    }
```

I also try this into my controller

```
public function boot()
    {
        return view('layouts/default')->with('user', Sentinel::getUser(););
    }
```

or

```
public function boot()    {
        view()->composer('layouts.default', function($view)     {
            $view->with('user', Sentinel::getUser());

        });     
    }
```

Still get "Undefined variable: user"

Comment: If ALL your views will use it, why not? just use `AppServiceProvider` as you call it. It works right ?

Comment: What does `$user = Sentinel::getUser()` return ? Try to `dd()` it.

Comment: $user = Sentinel::getUser();
        dd($user);
= null

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to call View::XXXXX within the boot method of a service provider...

The simplest is to call share on the view within your app service provider... this will make it available to all views... however take notice of when this value is resolved, it is resolved at boot time...

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::share('key', 'value');
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

You can also create a view composer that will be run prior to rendering a specific view or set of views... You can give it the view/class or view/closure... this will be evaluated before the view renders...

Bind a view composer class:

```
public function boot()
    {
        // Using class based composers...
        View::composer(
            'profile', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\ProfileComposer'
        );
}
```

Or attach a closure... and do what you need to boot that vie within that closure...

```
public function boot()
    {
        // Using Closure based composers...
        View::composer('dashboard', function ($view) {
            //
        });
}
```

You can bind to all views like the View::share... but push the evaluation to before the view render by using a simple closure based composer... in your case...

```
        // Using Closure based composers...
        View::composer('dashboard', function ($view) {
            $view->with('user', Sentinel::getUser() );
        });
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: With this : View::share('user', Sentinel::getUser());
I get this error : Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Added to the answer, try that... calling getUser() at boot time probably causes your Sentinel object to not be set-up yet... Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, define a function like that:

```
public function index() {
   $user = Sentinel::getUser();

   //The parameter of the view is your blade file relative to your directory
   //resources/views/default.blade.php
   return view('default')->with('user', $user);
}
```

In your web.php (routes file), add this

```
//First parameter is the url, second is the controller/function
Route::get('/', 'YourControllerName@index');
```

Now test the view in localhost [Optional]

http://localhost:8000

Comment: If I do this routes, it will only work on my index '/' not in all my subpages

Comment: The function boot() is not supposed to be load in every views ?